# Bower Configuration files template and Appsetting template even web/general template missing

Tags: asp.net

I was using `asp.net` core 2.0 with visual studio 2017 suddenly bower configuration files template missed out and even **Web/General** template disappeared

Comment: the files are in the project folder, they exist and were not loaded, they no longer exist in the project folder, provide details